# What is the possible cause of a Windows batch command preventing all subsequent commands to execute?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, exit

I have a simple bat file that does the following:

```
openapi-generator generate -i open-api-offline-file.json -g csharp-netcore -c open-api-config.json -o DataLakeOpenApiRestClient 

REM customizing ApiClient
xcopy .\SourcesCustomizations\ApiClient.cs .\DataLakeOpenApiRestClient\src\Org.OpenAPITools\Client\ApiClient.cs* /Y /F /R
```

If I run the command one by one in the console, they work correctly.

If I run the bat file the first executes successfully and the second does not seem to execute (I get generation messages and that's it). As if the first command somehow manages to exit preventing the other commands from executing.

I cannot figure out how this can happen.

**Question:** What is the possible cause of a batch command preventing all subsequent commands to execute?

Comment: The most simple reason may be that openapi-generator returns to batch file by the fact it was successfully started, not by the fact it finishes its operations. Try to wait for it terminates using `start /wait`. PS. Always add `pause` command to the end of your batch during debugging - this allows you to look at messages.

Comment: @Akina - yes you are right or in a more dev friendly words, the generation is done async. Please, consider promoting your comment to an answer. Now I am wondering who would want this as a default behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @Akina - I thought about this before asking here, but I could not find the output of the second command within the output generated by the first one, so I thought it is not executed at all.

Comment: What is `openapi-generator` -- is it a batch file too?

Comment: @aschipfl - it is a CLI (command line executable) used to generate API client for Open API REST services. Unfortunately, I could not find in its docs if it does the processing asynchronously (starts the processing as another process / thread and returns) or not. Even if it works async, I expected to see the subsequent command output mixed with the tool's own output.